# How to disable connection refresh on refresh all for all connections in 1 sheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have multiple Query Tables that I do not want to refresh when running a refresh all. I know I can manually go into the settings to do that but there are just too many and I would have to do it all the time.

I found a code to do so for the entire sheet but I want to have others with the setting on still. Below is the code that I found:

```
    Dim conn As Object
    For Each conn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
        conn.ODBCConnection.EnableRefresh = False
    Next
End Sub
```

Here is a screen shot of the specific setting I am talking about

[image]

Comment: How are the ones not disabled identified ? Is there a pattern in the name or description text ?

Comment: There is yes! Each table has a tag of MO######_*TableName*. They are duplicates referencing different data

Comment: Clarification, those are the ones I want to disable. The sheet names that I want to disable as well are labeled MO######

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a pattern in the name property of the connection. See [refreshwithrefreshall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbookconnection.refreshwithrefreshall)

```
    Dim conn As Object
    For Each conn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections 
        conn.RefreshWithRefreshAll = Not CBool(conn.Name LIKE "MO*")
    Next
```

Comment: @jarvis Ok last try, see my updated post. I think the property you want to change is `RefreshWithRefreshAll` not `ODBCConnection.EnableRefresh`

Comment: This revision worked! Thanks so much. accepted the answer

Comment: A note though, I did have to modify the criteria to be "*MO*". This might be because it seems when looking at the properties, the full name is "Query - MO######"

Comment: @jarvis I think that's a default name when you create it ,you can change it . You can delete some of your comments now.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to do basically the same thing but delete connections instead of not be refreshed?

Comment: @jarvis Don't see why not https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbookconnection.delete